# When will AWS lambda support python 3.9?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.9

Hi does anyone know how can I find out when will AWS lambda upgrade their support to python 3.9? Last time they upgraded to 3.8 was 2019 and it’s been a while since v3.9 released.

I’m keen to use the latest v3.9 language features but sadly can’t do it in AWS

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Update:

As of 16.08.2021 Python 3.9 is now supported:

> AWS Lambda now supports Python 3.9 as both a managed runtime and a container base image. You can now author AWS Lambda functions in Python 3.9 and use its new features, such as support for TLS 1.3, new string and dictionary operations, and improved time zone support. Python 3.9 also includes performance optimizations that you can benefit from without making any code changes. For more information on Lambda’s support for Python 3.9, see our blog post at Python 3.9 runtime now available in AWS Lambda.
>
> — [Source](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/08/aws-lambda-adds-support-python-3-9/)

---

#### Old Answer

AWS typically don't have a public roadmap for these, but you can now create a lambda function from a docker container that runs Python 3.9 if you want to use that version.

You'd have to build an image that includes the `awslambdaric` [package](https://pypi.org/project/awslambdaric/) from PyPi, which is the interface AWS uses to talk to Lambda. That package is compatible with python 3.9 already.

More information about building images for Lambda in Python see: [Deploy Python Lambda functions with container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html#python-image-clients)

Answer (score 6):

As of August 16th, 2021 Lambda runtime supports Python 3.9.

- [Read the official announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/python-3-9-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/)
- [Check out Lambda runtimes documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html)